# Xcode Simulator for iPhone 4 (960 x 640

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Is there an iPhone4 simulator supporting the new RD 960x640 resolution included within the next release of the iPhone SDK / Xcode?

much appreciated.

Gary

Comment: SDK 4 is still under NDA by Apple

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. It's supported. `Simulator` > `Hardware` > `Device` > `iPhone 4`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in the menu Hardware > Device of the simulator...

Answer (score 0):

Available in the SDK4 beta, which is currently only accessible by iPhone Developer Program members.

edit: now available for all developers.